# When to use/not to use protect_from_forgery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, authentication, antiforgerytoken

I know how to enable/disable authenticity token verification, but I don't know when it makes sense to enable it.

For example in a rails app, what I understood is the following. kindly let me know if I got it wrong

Web:

- public pages (unlogged) should enable authenticity token verification
- authentication pages (sign-in, sign-up, lost password ...) should enable authenticity token verification
- private pages (logged-in) do not need to enable authenticity token verification

Api:

- public api (unlogged, JSON access) should enable authenticity token verification
- authentication api (sign-in, sign-up, lost password ..., JSON access) should enable authenticity token verification
- private api (logged-in, JSON access) do not need to enable authenticity token verification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not correct that private pages do not need to enable CSRF protection. Private pages, where the user is authenticated, are the ones that are vulnerable to [CSRF](https://owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)). In this attack, somebody who is logged in is tricked (by clicking a link in an email, for example) into taking action they didn't intend to - which the site accepts, because it comes from a logged-in user with a valid session. `protect_from_forgery` prevents this by ensuring that non-`GET` requests can only be initiated from the site itself, by a user who is aware of the action they're taking.

Comment: Very clear thank you. What about JSON requests (coming from a mobile app for example)? I would guess there is no risk of being 'tricked' there right? Knowing that the cookies are "inside" the app, and the app does not accept external action that could be performed through a simple link.

Comment: You'll be vulnerable as long as it's possible for an attacker to trick a user into initiating the same request from some other context. For example, see the "POST scenario" section of https://owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF). Same Origin Policy restrictions would seem to make it more difficult to execute this attack for non-GET or -POST requests, but not impossible (see "Other HTTP methods" on that same page). My rule of thumb is: be very careful about assuming that a request can't be forged, and err on the side of enabling protection.